# How to change the Response StatusCode after the Request computing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I've something tricky to implement : in a controller action, for several reasons (legacy code), I have to overwrite the response **after** the request was computed.
I've done that with the following code :

```
HttpContext.Response.Buffer = false;
HttpContext.AddOnRequestCompleted(callbackFunction);
```

And after the Response is ready, to send it :

```
HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
```

Now, the problem is when the Response computing fail, I must change the StatusCode of the Response ; but I always obtain a 200.

Do you have any idea, please ?

Comment: AFAIK, if you disable buffering, the web server starts sending the response immediately. Given an HTTP response starts with a status line containing the status code, you can't change the status code after you've started sending a response.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller ?

```
Response.StatusCode = 666;
```